# For three vectors $x\leq y\leq z$ does $\min{\lbrace \|x\|^2, \|z\|^2}\rbrace \leq \|y\|^2\leq\max\lbrace{\|x\|^2, \|z\|^2\rbrace}$ hold

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, normed-spaces

We are given three vectors $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^n$. We know that the inequality $x\leq y\leq z$ holds, where $'\leq'$ has to be interpreted componentwise. Does this imply $\min\lbrace \|x\|_2^2, \|z\|_2^2\rbrace \leq \|y\|_2^2\leq\max \lbrace \|x\|_2^2, \|z\|_2^2 \rbrace$.

I am tempted to say yes, because of the monotony of the euclidean norm, but I cannot proof it.

Comment: Note that if you force the vectors in $\mathbf{R}_+^n,$ then the inequality you want does hold. This may be useful in statistical or economical applications where quantities are often compared vectorwise and they are nonnegative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work in general. Take for example $x=(-1,-1)$, $y=(0,0)$ and $z=(1,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $x \leq y \leq z$ as needed, but $\min\{\|x\|_2^2,\|z\|_2^2\} = \min\{2,2\} > 0 = \|y\|_2^2$.